# Issue with the MvcMusicStore Tutorial: step 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The link to the step I'm on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-4

1. Sub header "Adding Our Store Data"
   Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MvcMusicStore
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new MvcMusicStore.Models.SampleData());
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilter.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error with: RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilter.Filters);

The error is
CS0103: The name 'RegisterGlobalFilters' does not exist in the current context

I tried troubleshooting it for a little while then completely restarted the tutorial with a new file and ran into the problem again. Any idea what the issue could be?

P.S. I am still pretty new to coding, I'm at the beginning of my 3rd semester and this is a tutorial assigned to me by my boss at an internship. Any info helps, thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what version of Visual Studio that you're using. Did you notice that the tutorial that you referenced says "2010" (ie: Visual Studio 2010)? You may have a look at [ASP.NET MVC Version History](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/asp.net-mvc-version-history)

Comment: I'm using 2019 so that's probably my problem...

Comment: The tutorial there seems a bit old and probably why your getting issues.
I would be looking at ASP.Net 5 tutorial.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/
and perhaps even ASP.Net core depending on your placements current practices.

Comment: In the end, it's not too important which (core or MVC), what's important is the principles - controllers, models, views, and hopefully the code first database methods.